# Issue with C# CMD output

Tags: c#, cmd, process, activation

I am creating a C# app that changes Windows Server edition from Standard Evaluation to Standard. I am trying to get a output of the CMD command, but when the DISM command is completed, it asks you if you want to restart the computer and you need to enter "y" or "n". I tried it doing by passing "echo n | " before the command and by using process.StandardInput.Write, but none of this works. The function works perfectly with other commands that doesn´t require user input. Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
 public static string get_cmd_output(string cmd)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C echo n |  " + cmd;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.Start();
        

        string q = "";
        while (!process.HasExited)
            q += process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        return q;
    }

get_cmd_output("DISM /Online /Set-Edition:ServerStandard /ProductKey:" + key + " /AcceptEula");
```

Comment: Have you tried passing `/NoRestart` as one of the parameters?

Comment: Try adding a return after the "Y\n" or "N\n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [docs for DISM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-global-options-for-command-line-syntax#global-options-for-servicing-and-imaging-commands), one of the global parameters you can pass is `/NoRestart`:

> **/NoRestart**
>
> Suppresses reboot. If a reboot is not required, this command does
> nothing. This option will keep the application from prompting for a
> restart (or keep it from restarting automatically if the /Quiet option
> is used).

So it should work if you do this:

```
get_cmd_output("DISM /Online /Set-Edition:ServerStandard /ProductKey:" + key + " /AcceptEula /NoRestart");
```